# How do I create Recurring Billing in Pay Pal Developer account?

Tags: paypal

As with many people on this forum I have been completely confused by PayPal's new developer site and find myself with an issue regarding Recurring Billing.

I have successfully set up an account with which I can create a business account and personal account but when I try to create a recurring billing button, the system does not allow this as it expects you to be signed up to the premium service (quite why you need these kinds of permissions in a test site I don't know but there you go).  Anyway, when you click on the link to subscribe to the premium service the system throws you into the live system!!  This makes no sense whatsoever.

So my question is whether other people are in the same position as me and if anyone has actually been successfull in using recurring billing in one of PayPal's new test accounts.

Incidentally I am a UK customer and have a live paypal account which is subscribed to the premium services but I obviosuly want to test in sandbox mode not my live account!

I have had an e-mail from Merchant support to say that fixes are due in the next few days or so but just wondered what other people's experiences were so far.

Thanks

Steven

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of recurring features you are trying to use, this may have to be set up additionally on the account you are creating.  There are subscriptions, which are free to use and you can generate the HTML code for these from your account.  Then there is Enhanced Recurring Payments, basically these are similar to subscriptions but allow your buyers to pay with credit cards without having to have a PayPal account like subscriptions do.  You can also set up installment plans, and these buttons can be generated from your account.  Lastly there is Recurring Payments, like Enhanced Recurring Payments, this is a paid services as well.  This allows you to create recurring profiles using the API's, and also allows you to keep your buyers on your site without redirecting them to PayPal.

If you are needing a feature enabled on your account, if you can provide your ticket number and the test sandbox seller account you are needing this feature enabled on I will take a look at it and see if I can make the toggles from my end.

Comment: Chad, thanks for the response, all details are on this ticket number: #130314-000209.  And by the way I may be using incorrect terminology but the feature I need is Automatic Billing which requires the test account to be signed up to Website Payments Standard Premium Service.  Thanks Steven

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at your ticket and reply to you through your ticket.